# Awful game stuttering on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and other distros based on this version

Tags: kubuntu, 22.04, games, amd-graphics, mint

I've had this issue on multiple games now where the game feels and looks like it's running at 20fps whenever it drops even a bit below 60. Turning off Vsync makes it worse, with the game looking laggy at even above 60fps. I have tested on fresh installs of Ubuntu 22.04, Kubuntu 22.04, KDE Neon, Linux Mint 21.3 (this one being my main distro) and they all have this issue. Ubuntu 22.10 and 23.04 however, do not. Any ideas what could be causing it? Thanks!

inxi output:

```
> System:
  Host: ovidiu-pc Kernel: 5.19.0-41-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A
    Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.24.7 Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Desktop System: ASUS product: All Series v: N/A
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: ASUSTeK model: H81M-C v: Rev X.0x serial: <superuser required>
    BIOS: American Megatrends v: 3501 date: 10/21/2016
CPU:
  Info: quad core model: Intel Xeon E3-1240 v3 bits: 64 type: MT MCP
    arch: Haswell rev: 3 cache: L1: 256 KiB L2: 1024 KiB L3: 8 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 806 high: 850 min/max: 800/3800 cores: 1: 800 2: 800
    3: 850 4: 800 5: 800 6: 800 7: 800 8: 800 bogomips: 54399
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590]
    vendor: Sapphire Nitro+ driver: amdgpu v: kernel bus-ID: 01:00.0
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.3 driver: X: loaded: amdgpu,ati
    unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,vesa gpu: amdgpu resolution: 1: 1920x1080~60Hz
    2: 1920x1080~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: AMD Radeon RX 580 Series (polaris10 LLVM 15.0.6 DRM
    3.47 5.19.0-41-generic)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 22.2.5 direct render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel 8 Series/C220 Series High Definition Audio vendor: ASUSTeK
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 00:1b.0
  Device-2: AMD Ellesmere HDMI Audio [Radeon RX 470/480 / 570/580/590]
    vendor: Sapphire driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 01:00.1
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.19.0-41-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet
    vendor: ASUSTeK H81M-C driver: r8169 v: kernel port: d000 bus-ID: 03:00.0
RAID:
  Message: No RAID data found.
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 1.59 TiB used: 353.83 GiB (21.7%)
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Seagate model: ST3500418AS size: 465.76 GiB
  ID-2: /dev/sdb vendor: Seagate model: ST3500418AS size: 465.76 GiB
  ID-3: /dev/sdc vendor: Western Digital model: WD5000AAKX-08U6AA0
    size: 465.76 GiB
  ID-4: /dev/sdd type: USB vendor: Western Digital
    model: WD2500BMVV-11GNWS0 size: 232.86 GiB
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 227.65 GiB used: 13.37 GiB (5.9%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sdd3
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 512 MiB used: 6.1 MiB (1.2%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/sdd2
Info:
  Processes: 294 Uptime: 29m Memory: 15.56 GiB used: 4.1 GiB (26.4%)
  Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: N/A Packages: 1990 Shell: Bash
  v: 5.1.16 inxi: 3.3.13
```

Comment: If you have a question about Ubuntu this is the place. Anything to do with the other OS is off topic.

Comment: I believe it gives meaningful context, showing that this is not some issue caused by some changes I might've inadvertently made to my OS, but that it occurs in fresh installs of multiple distros, all built upon the same common Ubuntu base

Comment: Eh... meaningful context would be the make/model of the hardware you're asking about, especially since it's the most important detail... It's hard to answer the question *"How do I get XYZ hardware to work"* when you don't tell us the make and model of the hardware  Anyway, it sounds like your card may not be supported well on an older stack. If it works on Ubuntu 22.10 and Ubuntu 23.04, then you should use one of those releases.

Comment: Meaningful context would also be the titles and version numbers of the problematic software you are trying to run. Again, it's hard to answer the question, *"Why is XYZ software not working the way I want"* when you never tell us what software you're trying to run.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the answer. It seems that switching from x11 to wayland did the trick. And to think that I spent days trying to figure it out... *facepalm*

Answer (score 0):

That's a common problem with the new kernels. Split lock detection is at fault here.

You need to disable it.

Edit `/etc/default/grup` file, append the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` in the quotes on said line add a space at the end and `split_lock_detect=off`.

The line should look like the following...

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=on split_lock_detect=off"`